# C# Regex - Match specific string followed by a substring1 or substring2

Tags: c#, regex

**Input**: `This AbT5xY\nAppleUvW is a test AbT5xY AppleUvW is a test and AbT5xrAppleUvW and another AbT5xY\nmangoUvW test`

Following RegEx gives the output: `This SomeFruitUvW is a test SomeFruitUvW is a test and AbT5xrAppleUvW and another SomeFruitUvW test.`

```
Regex.Replace(st, "AbT5xY\\s*(Apple)|(mango)", "SomeFruit");
```

But what I need is that if `AbT5xY` is followed by `Apple` then replace `AbT5xYApple` with `Fruit1`; and if `AbT5xY` is followed by `mango` replace `AbT5xYmango` with `Fruit2`. Hence,

**Desired output**: `This Fruit1UvW is a test Fruit1UvW is a test and AbT5xrAppleUvW and another Fruit2UvW test.`

**Note**:

1. I'm ignoring whitespace characters (newline, blanks, tabs etc.) between `AbT5xY` and Apple or `AbT5xY` and mango. Also `AbT5xrAppleUvW` is correctly not matched since it has `AbT5xr` and not `AbT5xY` before Apple.
2. I think C#'s RegEx has something called substitutions, groups, captures that need to be used here but I'm struggling with how to use these here.

Comment: Just do 2 Regexes and replace 2 times. I don't think you can do it any other way

Comment: Just try to use overrides of `Replace(string input, string pattern, MatchEvaluator evaluator)` where your custom `MatchEvaluator` will give you correct value that you want for matching string value

Comment: @JakubDąbek I just added note 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may capture the `Apple` and `mango` into Group 1 and when replacing, use a match evaluator, where you can check the Group 1 value, and then perform the necessary replacement based on the check result:

```
var pat = @"AbT5xY\s*(Apple|mango)";
var s = "This AbT5xY\nAppleUvW is a test AbT5xY AppleUvW is a test and AbT5xrAppleUvW and another AbT5xY\nmangoUvW test";
var res = Regex.Replace(s, pat, m =>
        m.Groups[1].Value == "Apple" ? "Fruit1" : "Fruit2");
Console.WriteLine(res);
// => This Fruit1UvW is a test Fruit1UvW is a test and AbT5xrAppleUvW and another Fruit2UvW test
```

See the [C# demo](http://ideone.com/jZjQJ6).

The `AbT5xY\s*(Apple|mango)` regex matches `AbT5xY`, then 0+ whitespaces (note a single backslash as I used a *verbatim* string literal) and then matches and captures either `Apple` or `mango` into Group 1. The `m.Groups[1].Value == "Apple"` if Group 1 value is `Apple`, and then proceeds to replace the match.

Comment: From your solution I also learned how to use LINQ for match evaluator - that comes handy if the corresponding evaluation is not too complex.

Comment: @nam I'm being picky here but there is no LINQ in here, but a lambda expression. The semantics are quite confusing as people see lambdas almost primarily in LINQ queries.

Comment: @JakubDąbek Agreed. Linq uses Lambda expression in order to execute some of its functionalities